# template deduction evaluates to overload of identical functions

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading

I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  void bar(double val);
  void bar(T val);
  T m_val;
};
```

Now the problem is if I instantiate an object of type `Foo<double>`, I get two overloaded functions with identical signatures.

Is there any way around it?

My problem is that I indeed need to treat the case where `val` is of type `double` special. Furthermore, the `bar` parameters of non-double type don't have a common superclass.

Comment: What behavior would you like when you instantiate a `Foo<double>`? Would you like it to use the definition of `bar` with `T` as a parameter, or the one with `double`?

Comment: @Jon McClung, thanks for your comment. I would like to use the one with double.

Comment: Use enable_if to disable the generic one for double

Comment: @ Yan Zhou nice idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another aproach is to disable function with SFINAE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
 void bar(double val){
     std::cout << "bar(double)\n";
 }

  template<class Y=T>
  typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Y, double>::value>::type  
  bar(T val){
      std::cout << "bar(T)\n";
      }

  T m_val;
};

int main()
{
  Foo<double> dd;
  dd.bar(1.0);

  Foo<std::string> dd2;
  dd2.bar("asds");
  dd2.bar(1.0);
}
```

[edit]

as W.F pointed out in comment, you dont need enable_if here, making `bar(T)` a template member function will suffice to disambiguate it:

```
template<int=0>
void bar(T val){
  std::cout << "bar(T)\n";
}
```

Comment: I think making the bar template by itself would make compiler prefer non-template overload - no need to use enable_if here actually...

Comment: @marcinj I think I undestand W.F. comment but why exactly do we need template<int=0> ?

Comment: @user695652 there is return type, default for enable_if is `void`

Answer (score 5):

You can create template specialization. In specialization of template classes or functions you define unique behavior for a certain type. For example:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
   void bar(T);
   T m_val;
}

template <>
struct Foo<double> {
   void bar(double);
   double m_val;
};
```

Or you can specialize only one function for this case:

```
template <>
void Foo<double>::bar(double);
```

Now when you do following:

```
int main() {
   Foo<double> ob1;
   Foo<int> obj2;

   obj1.bar(1,3);
   obj2.bar(45);
   return 0;
}
```

obj1.bar calls bar function from specialization.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you expand it a bit, I don't see how I can call `bar` with a non double value in your approach.

Comment: i hope it satisfies your question, if not feel free to ask